# how to usort an array which is already sorted with another key

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

my first array is already sorted by name,but i want to usort it with position,
what i have tried is here,
array before usort

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => admin
            [designation] => admin
            [email] => admin@admin
            [phone] => 999777788
            [ext] => 67767
            [position] => 1
            [image] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ATeam
            [designation] => Manager
            [email] => service@mail.com
            [phone] => 
            [ext] => 777
            [position] => 3
            [image] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => BTeam
            [designation] => Manager
            [email] =>g@mail.co.in
            [phone] => 
            [ext] => 
            [position] => 4
            [image] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => hi team
            [designation] => new
            [email] => abc
            [phone] => 3333
            [ext] => 333
            [position] => 10
            [image] =>
        )
[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => new team
        [designation] => maneger
        [email] => mg@g
        [phone] => 445567676
        [ext] => ext
        [position] => 10
        [image] => 
    )
```

)

usort function i applied to the array is:

```
usort($a_teams,function($a,$b){
          if($a['position'] == '') return 1;
          if($b['position'] == '') return -1;
          return $a['position']-$b['position'];
        });
```

the result array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => admin
            [designation] => admin
            [email] => admin@admin
            [phone] => 999777788
            [ext] => 67767
            [position] => 1
            [image] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ATeam
            [designation] => Manager
            [email] => service@mail.com
            [phone] => 
            [ext] => 777
            [position] => 3
            [image] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => BTeam
            [designation] => Manager
            [email] => g@mail.co.in
            [phone] => 
            [ext] => 
            [position] => 4
            [image] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => new team
            [designation] => maneger
            [email] => mg@g
            [phone] => 445567676
            [ext] => ext
            [position] => 10
            [image] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => hi team
            [designation] => new
            [email] => abc
            [phone] => 3333
            [ext] => 333
            [position] => 10
            [image] => 
        )

)
```

but the problem is the alphabetical order of `name` is not getting in proper order when the `positions` is same

Comment: So in `usort` check both `name` and `position`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the usort function for sorting by position and name:

```
usort($a_specials,function($a,$b){
    if($a['position'] == '') return 1;
    if($b['position'] == '') return -1;
    if($a['position'] == $b['position'])
        return strnatcmp($a['title'],$b['title']);
    return $a['position']-$b['position'];
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Changed the usort function for sorting by position and name:

```
 usort($a_teams,function($a,$b){
if ($a["position"]==$b["position"]){
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}     
return ($a["position"]<$b["position"])?-1:1;
```

});